# Jetstor SAN disk firmware

Tags: hard-drive, storage-area-network, firmware

We have a jetstor SAN, specifically http://www.9to5computer.com/AC&NC/JetStor%20SATA%20412iS%20iSCSI%20to%20SATA%20Rackmount%20Raid.htm and now discontinued.

Its run for 6 years and just hit end of warranty. Vendor will provide a disk only warranty for another year and we're planning to upgrade in a year or so, budget depending. As they have us over the proverbial barrel they want a lot of money to provide disks.

The disks they quote are:

JetStor Seagate ST1000NM0033 1TB SATA Drive for JetStor SAS412iS - they are just Seagate ST1000NM0033 with a modified firmware. They wont tell us (of course) what happens if we used an unmodified disk off the shelf. We probably shouldnt try but does anyone happen to know? Considering the bare enterprise model is about 10% of the quoted price, we're just seeing if we can avoid the expensive warranty for the next year or so and what risk.

We have asked the Vendor but quite rightly they wont help.

I understand this is not the best practice, just want to see if anyone has any idea what would happen.

Comment: Serverfault is a site for professional sysadmins who inherently want to work with supported/supportable system - this sounds innately dangerous so we would not suggest you carry out your plan.

Answer (score 2):

I have quite a few Dell SAN and certified as a Dell Technician, not the same brand as you, but the firmware used make a big difference on the SAN.

How? An example, I know that some firmware will allow the SAN to quickly snapshot the disk to a another disk in case a fail will happen, to save a lot of rebuild time.. this is only one feature I talk about, but be assured that yes, it got some use.

You can use a bunch of soho disk too, but you scrap the SAN resiliency.

Answer (score 0):

We have several JetStor arrays. We have been replacing failed drives in them for years by using off the shelf hard drives. They don't even need to be the same model. As long as the specs are the same, it has worked for us.